# How to toggle a div after clicking javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, hide

I'm trying to use a div to show game rules, so when they select the "button" it will reveal the rules, but I can't get it to close by reselecting it. I have tried a few other solutions but they are not quite what I am looking for.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('howto').style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<input type="button" name="rules" value="How to Play!" onclick="showDiv()" />
<div id="howto"  style="display:none;" class="rules" > WELCOME</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a `toggleDiv` rather than `showDiv` function that checks the display style and sets it to whichever of `block` or `none` it is not currently set to. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleDiv() {
 var div = document.getElementById('howto'); 
 div.style.display = (div.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
}
</script>

<input type="button" name="rules" value="How to Play!" onclick="toggleDiv()" />
<div id="howto"  style="display:none;" class="rules" > WELCOME</div>
```

Comment: OMG thank you i couldn't figure out for the life of me why it wasn't letting me and it was so simple... just the `toggleDiv` lol thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. If my reply (or some other reply) helped you, please consider accepting it as an answer.

Comment: was in the process it just stated I had to wait five minutes to accept your speedy answer friend!